# i have tow table which contain on same column like UserID. How to get all row by subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have tow table which contain on same column like UserID

```
1. employee 
--------------------------------------------------------
id     UserID       Name         Description
1      username1    fullName1   employee Description1
2      username2    fullName2   employee Description2
--------------------------------------------------------

2. user_info
--------------------------------------------------------
id     UserID       password
1      username1     password1
2      username2     password2

--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have user_info data. I want to employee table row according to user_info data By "Subquery"
just i want to use subquery syntax

Comment: Are you using a database?  Please tag your question with the software you are using.

Comment: mysql database driver

Comment: @SalmanQuader Look at this - [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: I want to use subquery. do you have any subquery syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you just want a subquery, but try this, maybe works;)

```
select e.*
from employee e
where exists (
    select 1 from user_info u
    where e.UserID = u.UserID
)
-- maybe some conditions else need, you can add it by yourself
```

Or you also can try this,

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.UserID in (
    select u.UseID from user_info u
)
```

Anyway, perhaps other solution exists...